# Javascript Else Statement Being Executed Despite If Statement Being True

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I am attempting to implement a 3-state html label with javascript that iterates between 3 different css class names when the user click on the label. I've used a simple if -> else if -> else if statement to toggle between the 3 class states, but for some reason, it is always executing both the first true if statement and then the next else statement even though it already hit a true if statement first.

I'm a bit perplexed how this is happening as else statements are supposed to be skipped after a true if statement is hit.

Here's my code:

```
$(".goal-label").on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('active_goal')) {
        alert('has active_goal');
        $(this).removeClass('active_goal');
        return $(this).addClass('complete_goal');
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('complete_goal')) {
        alert('has complete_goal');
        $(this).removeClass('complete_goal');
        return $(this).addClass('failed_goal');
      } else if ($(this).hasClass('failed_goal')) {
        $(this).removeClass('failed_goal');
        return $(this).addClass('active_goal');
      }
    });
```

So the initial class on the label is "active_goal" and when I click on it I see the alert "has active_goal" and I then I immediately see another alert "has complete_goal" which is inside the else if statement after the if statement that is being triggered by the label having the class "active_goal".

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: It seems more likely that the event handler is being invoked multiple times than that the `if` structure in JavaScript is broken.

Comment: Interesting, thank makes sense. Any idea how I could debug that? What would make an on click event get triggered twice on click?

Comment: You were absolutely right, I added an alert with a counter at the beginning of the on click function and it was indeed calling it twice every time the goal-label is clicked. Now I just have to try down what would be causing it to get called twice.

Comment: The class it’s matching on could match multiple nested elements?  The click event may propagate up through them.  Try replicating the behavior in a sandbox, such as a code snippet in the question.

Comment: @David the element with class "goal-label" only appears once in the HTML, so that doesn't appear to be the case. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: Also, the click event doesn't appear to be getting bound twice. I tried clearing it with off before binding it and I added alerts before binding it and neither seemed to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what was causing my click events to trigger twice but I discovered that adding a `return false` at the end of the click function stopped it from happening the second time so everything seems to be working now.